# Set the maxNativeZoom before blank page in mapbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

We're using the leaflet JavaScript API with a tile layer which supports. in different place different zooming level supports some place 17 and some place 19 .I'd like to zoom about supports the zooming level in different place if not supports zoom level that time maxNativeZoom will be set 17 0r 19 depends on zooming level supports,that i want stretch  the map not before zooming level supports  Is this possible ? any one get this ans please reply me (**already i used maxNativeZoom set 17 its working fine but after 17 its stretch  i want stretch when zooming level not supports** )